# SQL with AND in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I have a mySQL table named 'values' :

```
values:

file | metadata | value
________________________
01   | duration | 50s
01   | size     | 150mo
01   | extension| avi
02   | duration | 20s
02   | extension| mkv
03   | duration | 20s
03   | extension| mpeg
```

An user will create his own query in SQL, it will look like this :

```
SELECT file FROM values WHERE (metadata='duration' AND value='20s') AND (metadata='extension' AND value='mkv')
```

I know this query is bad, but I can't change the 'values' table. I don't know how to get the file_id with these conditions..

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: do you want only the file ids without duplication

Comment: try using OR condition

Comment: I think the OP wants to query for "duration" AND "extension" as if they were colums ... right, Kib?

Comment: I think you want both results that satisfies either 
(metadata='duration' AND value='20s') OR (metadata='extension' AND value='mkv').
Isn't it?
If YES, You are placing AND instead of OR.

Comment: yes without duplication is better !
@Fildor you got it ! if i use OR condition it will return me file_id 2 and 3 (because of their durations=20s)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT file
FROM
(
  SELECT file,
    MAX(CASE WHEN metadata = 'duration' THEN value END) AS duration,
    MAX(CASE WHEN metadata = 'extension' THEN value END) AS extension
  FROM `values`
  WHERE metadata IN ('duration', 'extension') 
  GROUP BY file
) AS sub
WHERE duration = '20s' AND extension = 'mkv';
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc4e9/10)

---

### Update

If you want to do this dynamically, and assuming that these metadata names are stored in a new separate table, then you can use the dynamic sql to do this. Something like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @cols = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(m.metadata_name = ''',
      m.metadata_name, ''', v.value, 0)) AS ', '''',   m.metadata_name, '''')
  ) INTO @cols
FROM Metadata AS m;

SET @sql = CONCAT('
  SELECT 
    v.file, ', @cols ,'
  FROM `values` AS v
  INNER JOIN metadata AS m ON v.metadata_id = m.metadata_id
  GROUP BY v.file');

prepare stmt 
FROM @sql;

execute stmt;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddcac/5)

Then you can put this inside a stored procedure and use it to display them, or query them the way you want.

Comment: Very nice, you are using 'pivot table' isn'it ? 
It's difficult to use if there are many metadata which can change (add or delete metadata) but i will work with that ! Thank you !

Comment: @Kib' - You're welcome any time :) Yes, I am pivoting the table. You can put that in a stored procedure that do that dynamically for all the metadata, then pass the parameters to it directly. It will be easy this way.

Comment: ^^ ! cool~ ! i'm very interesting by this way, i will create an other table 'metadata_name' that will populated this query dynamically ! thank you again.

Comment: @Kib' - You're welcome again :) See my edit for the dynamic version, it will give you all the metadata names as columns' headers.

Comment: this is totally awesome ! you save me from many hours of work ! unfortunately i have a problem : variable @ cols is too short;
i have more than 150 metadata in my table metadata ^^' .. i try to find a solution in the MySQL documentation, maybe you known a solution ? i will comment here if i find how to do

Comment: that make me sad ! if there are many metadata it doesn't work ! i'll create a new topic for this problem if i have not resolve this tomorrow

Comment: @Kib' - Sorry for that :( I have no idea how to handle this, I tried to declare variables with high sizes `DECLARE cols VARCHAR(8000); DECLARE s VARCHAR(8000);` and use it inside a stored procedure, but it didn't work. It seems like the `prepare` accepts only those session variables declared with `@`, here is the demo I tried: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f91b/2

Comment: thank you for your time, indeed i tried with variable like that : `DECLARE new_var TEXT DEFAULT ''` but didn't work too ! there is a new topic for this problem, hope a solution will be find ! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230749/sql-stored-procedure-variable-too-short)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT file FROM `values` 
WHERE (metadata='duration'  AND value='20s') 
OR    (metadata='extension' AND value='mkv')
```

- `VALUES` is reserved key word for mysql , use backticks around it

**EDIT:**

you should have table like that

```
 file | size | duration | extension |
  1   | 150mo|  50s     | avi
  2   | null |  20s     | mkv
  3   | null |  20s     | mpeg
```

then you query will be

```
    select file from `values` where duration = '20s' and extension = 'mkv'
```

Comment: it will return me file_id 2 and 3, whereas file_id 3 has no extension=mkv :/

Comment: that's a solution but i can't change the structure of the table (even if it will be more easy for me..) thanks to you !

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear what you want to achieve. I guess you want all results that are either "duration" & "20s" or "extensions" and "mkv". So you should just replace or middle "AND" with "OR".

```
SELECT file FROM values WHERE (metadata='duration' AND value='20s') OR (metadata='extension' AND value='mkv')
```

Comment: sorry to not be clear, i would like to have both of these conditions on the same file

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    v.file 
FROM values AS v 
WHERE (v.metadata='duration' AND v.value='20s') 
  OR (v.metadata='extension' AND v.value='mkv')
```

Comment: it will return me file_id 2 and 3, whereas file_id 3 has no extension=mkv :/

Answer (score 0):

using exists for 2th condition :

```
SELECT distinct file FROM values WHERE (metadata='duration' AND value='20s') AND
exists (  SELECT * FROM values as v2 where v2.metadata='extension' AND v2.value='mkv' and v2.file=values.file )
```

Comment: good idea, but in case of many conditions, it will become not easy to use ? but thanks for this tips